# how many days required to process request to enable Twilio numbers for WhatsApp

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

We are working with Twilio WhatsApp APIs in a sandbox environment. To start using the Twilio API for WhatsApp in production, need to enable Twilio numbers for WhatsApp.

On this URL Twilio give form to request https://www.twilio.com/whatsapp/request-access

But there is no fixed number of days specified for completion of this request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is no fixed number of days specified because the process is out of our hands and entirely under the control of WhatsApp at this stage. They are controlling the rollout of their API.

We made the [Twilio Sandbox for WhatsApp](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api#twilio-sandbox-for-whatsapp) available so that you could start building before WhatsApp complete their process, hopefully it helps. All you can do then is wait for WhatsApp

The only other thing I can suggest is to [get in touch with sales](https://www.twilio.com/help/sales) to describe your use case and potential usage to see what they can suggest in the meantime.